# Odd Apache Rewrite when file doesn't exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

It seems the behaviour of `RewriteCond` is affected whether a file is found or not.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

If a image (or js, css) files exists it will load fine. If the file doesn't exist, the /index.php?$1 rule matches rather than just display a 404.

http://example.com/images/file_exists.jpg = /images/file_exists.jpg [OK]

http://example.com/images/file_does_not_exist.jpg = /index.php?/images/file_does_not_exist.jpg [Not OK]

Note - I'm on shared host and aware that they may be doing things to the REQUEST_URI, however from my script I can see that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/images/file_does_not_exist.jpg'`, which indicates to me that it should work.

Comment: There must be something else going on here. Rules are not processed any differently because a file exists or not, unless the rules themselves test for the existence of a file. The URI processing happens before any attempt to serve the file is made (and generate a 404 when failed). Please post your full config or implement logging for mod_rewrite with "LogLevel rewrite:trace3" and post the log. However that cannot go in a `.htaccess` file so you may not be able to do it on shared hosting. In that case please just post your full config.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps I've updated with full .htaccess contents which sits in the root

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait to see if you make any progress resolving this with starkeen's answer before looking any further

Answer (score 2):

This is because RewriteRule runs before ErrorDocument. If you are handling 404 uris using ErrorDocument, the ErrorDocument wont work here as your rule rewrites everything to index.php. To solve this you need to handle your 404 requests using mod rewrite. put the following before your existing rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /404.php [L]
```

Comment: Good answer, but if this was the case, the rewritten URI would be `index.php?/404.php` wouldn't it? But the question shows it's the image URI getting passed through.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised this is working.. I'll just need to add more conditions so this only applies to the 'static' content type directories like images, css and js

Comment: I assume this should read "RewriteRule runs *after* ErrorDocument"

Answer (score 1):

This is not, as a I first thought the RewriteCond being skipped. In fact an ErrorDocument is an internal redirect which matches my 'catch all' rule.

Part of my confusion was that my local instance had no ErrorDocument directive, therefore the [default 'hardcoded' message](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ErrorDocument) was being used - therefore no redirect.

Secondly I realise now that `REQUEST_URI` is not changed by internal rewrites, even by ErrorDocument. I am not sure how this is different with other webservers, but something to be careful with in the future.

I am now explicitly setting an `ErrorDocument 404` in .htaccess to avoid the differences between dev and live environments, otherwise my config is unchanged as I realise it's working as expected.